# How to sort properties by name in IntelliJ IDEA debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-idea2017

Is there any way to sort the properties of an object by their names when using the Java debugger?

For example, I'm seeing this:

[image: intellij debugging view]

And I'd like to see this:

[image: debugging ordered]

Comment: there is a plugin provided by intellj, take a look at the following link
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4055-property-sorter

Comment: This plugin sorts the properties of a `.properties` file. In my case, I'm looking for a solution to sort the properties/fields of a POJO.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no separate option for *sorting only fields alphabetically*, but IDEA provides the feature **"Sort Values Alphabetically"** in the debug tool window.

It sorts both variables and their members in alphabetical order.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (having variables also sorted is not a problem). Thank you !

Comment: What is the default order?

Comment: @DanDascalescu the order they declared in?

Comment: is it also possible to sort watches vs variables?

Answer (score 7):

- Ultimate 2019.3
- Open services
- Click on the left on the 'wheel' settings.
- Activate sort values alphabetically.

2 screen dumps to help the reader to find the configuration.
[image]

[image]